# How to handle Test cases for function which returns Promise with resolve and reject in Angular 6

Tags: typescript, promise, angular6, karma-jasmine

I am writing test case for the function which returns Promise with resolve and reject as follows:

```
isAuthSuccess(): Promise<any> {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (this.userInfo) {
        resolve();
      } else {
        const validUserUrl: string = this.cookieService.get('PPRC_VALID_USER');
        if (validUserUrl) {
          this.authenticateUser(validUserUrl)
            .toPromise()
            .then(
              userInfo => {
                if (userInfo) {
                  this.userInfo = userInfo;
                  this.loadResources(userInfo, resolve);
                } else {
                  reject('500_1');
                }
              },
              error => {
                reject('500_1');
              }
            );
          } else {
            reject('500_1');
          }
      }
    });
    return promise;
  }
```

I am new in writing test cases for the function which handles promise. Checked few options but did not get any success. Please help me on the above to handle the test cases for positive and negative scenarios.

Comment: https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async

Comment: anybody got solution on this

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing an **async** function? The simple async/await combination below could be enough.

```
it("your test case name", async function() {
  await obj.isAuthSuccess();
  // expect(...).toBe(...);
});
```

Comment: I tried like this but it would be great if I get a complete test case for positive and negative scenario